# Front View Controller stays open

Tags: ios, swift2, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController to implement a slide view.  Upon sliding, the rear view controller is opened.  However, when I select an item in the table, the new 'destination' controller is correctly invoked, but the front view controller stays open. Any idea how I can get rid of this?
There is a navigation controller (A) between SWRevealViewController and rear view and a second navigation controller (B) between SWRevealViewController and front view.  Tried several combinations with varying results, but none correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the matter via a "quick and dirty".
1) I save the result of the user choice in the rear view controller
2) I close the slide by calling:
 self.revealViewController().revealToggle(self)
3) I process the result of the user selection in the main logic stream

Hope it helps if you are having similar problems